# UITableViewController datasource not reading new values

Tags: swift, uitableview, datasource, subclass

I have the following model, base UITableViewController class, and a subclass of the UITableViewController:

**Model**

```
class Product {

    var title: String
    var prices: [Int]

}
```

**UITableViewController - Superclass**

```
class BaseTableController: UITableviewController {

    var items: [Product] = [Product]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchData()
    }

    // MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
        let item = items[indexPath.item]
        Logger.debug("FOUND \(item.prices.count) PRICES")
        return cell
    }

    // MARK: - Data

    func fetchData() {
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

        items.forEach { (item) in
            dispatchGroup.enter()
            APIService.shared.getPrices(product: item) { (prices) in
                item.prices = prices
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
        }

        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

}
```

**UITableViewController - Subclass**

```
class MyFancyTable: BaseTableController {

    override var items: [Product] {
        set {}
        get {
            return [
                Product(title: "FOOD"),
                Product(title: "DRINK")
            ]
        }
    }

}
```

I'll be using MyFancyTable to fetch prices from different product category.

When the API returns a response, it will update the prices in the `items` variable and then I reload the table.

However, when I override `items` in the subclass (MyFancyTable), even though the prices has been updated during the API callback, the logger (in the cellForRowAtIndexPath) still reads zero prices. As if it was never updated.

Log result:

`FOUND 0 PRICES` - for FOOD

`FOUND 0 PRICES` - for DRINK

I can confirm the API returns a number of prices.

Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You're never entering the DispatchGroup.

Comment: I don't see how you are pulling items.

Comment: I'm sorry I stripped out a lot of code to make it more readable (code part updated).

Comment: Did you set breakpoints to make sure that the `reloadData()` is getting called?

Comment: @Xcoder, yes... I can confirm the `reloadData()` is called. It then went to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` again, which prints out 0 prices found for both products.

Comment: @CNVSO Great. When reloadData gets called, set a breakpoint and check the value of the `items` array.

Comment: @Xcoder, I did. I have 2 breakpoints set up...
Inside the API callback, after I set the new prices, I can see that item has X number of prices.
After `reloadData()`, the second breakpoint hit inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, which reads 0 prices found in the item object.

Comment: Is it not because you are overriding the get on your items object? You're telling it to always return  [
                Product(title: "FOOD"),
                Product(title: "DRINK")
            ]

Comment: @CameronPorter, hmm I think you're into something here. Is there a better way to override it so that API will update the proper object. The idea is, I want to use the subclass in different screens and just manipulate the `items` to show different product categories.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem might cause you're set `items` variable as computed property, that means it's recalculated every time it's called

try this :

```
class MyFancyTable: BaseTableController {

     override var items: [Product] = [Product(title: "FOOD"),Product(title: "DRINK")]
}
```

Comment: When I tried to override it this way, xcode gives me this error: `Cannot override with a stored property 'items'`

Comment: uhm, I think you should change your concept, in the `BaseTableController` you can setup your UI, `tableView` for example, and in its subclass you implement `fetchData` and declare `items` property

Comment: Thanks man, I've posted the solution based on your recommendation. 

Answer (score 0):

I've finally come up with a fix (based on the recommendation by Tung Vu Duc). Basically I need to override the `items` inside an `init` function in the subclass instead doing it via a computed-property as I originally did.

The subclass now looks like:

```
class MyFancyTable: BaseTableController {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

        items = [
            Product(title: "FOOD"),
            Product(title: "DRINK")
        ]
    }

}
```

Thanks everyone!